# Interuptiong active threads

Tags: java

I'm trying to interrupt active threads created in Restart() using Terminate() they both extend Event(). I have it set up so Terminate would change the value of terminate to true but I can't get the setter to change the value of terminate outside of Terminate():
Here is the relevant code:
**Restart.java:**

```
public class Restart extends Event {
...
    public void action() {
    ...
for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
            Class<?> eventClass;

            try {
                eventClass = Class.forName(eventList.get(i));
                Object eventObject;
                if (eventList.get(i).equals("Bell")) {
                    eventObject = eventClass.getConstructor(long.class, int.class).newInstance(timeList.get(i), rings);
                }

                else {
                    eventObject = eventClass.getConstructor(long.class).newInstance(timeList.get(i));
                }

                eventThread = new Thread((Runnable) eventObject);
                eventThread.start();
            }

            catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Terminate.java**

```
public class Terminate extends Event {

    public Terminate(long delayTime) {
        super(delayTime);
    }

    public void action() {
        setTerminate(true);
        System.out.println(getTerminate());
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Terminating";
    }
}
```

**Event.java**

```
public abstract class Event implements Runnable {
  ...
  public boolean terminate;
  ...
  public void setTerminate(boolean terminate) {
    this.terminate = terminate;
  }

  public boolean getTerminate() {
    return terminate;
  }
 public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(delayTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      System.out.println(getTerminate());
      while (getTerminate()) {
        eventThread.interrupt();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      System.out.println(this.toString());
      this.action();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add the `volatile` keyword to `terminate`, ie `public volatile boolean terminate;`. Without this keyword, other threads may not see the value change.

Comment: @Bohemian Just tried that didn't change anything, should I be changing anything other than adding `volatile`?

Comment: It seems like you want the [poison pill](https://dzone.com/articles/producers-and-consumers-part-3) pattern.  Maybe just do that: the task processor as a Runnable in a single thread that simply returns when the next task to be processed is the poison pill. You've almost got that, but your poison pill does that exiting rather than the consumer, which is much more complicated and unreliable due to concurrency.

Comment: @Bohemian I looked at the link but I don't fully understand what you mean could you possibly dumb it down for me a bit?